# jquery each input hasClass

Tags: jquery, input, each

For my needs I use

```
$('#form :input').each( function(i) {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('donot') ) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

is there **a better way** to not use **the if condition** to check if the input has the class 'donot' ?

Thanks for your help...

Chris

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#form input:not(.donot)').each( function(i) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

And there you go :-D

[Docs for `:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

---

Or you can also do:

```
$('#form input').not('.donot').each( function(i) {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

[Docs for `.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: @user1080344 no problem ^_^ happy to help :-D

Answer (score 3):

Try this and also you don't even need each loop to do this.

```
$('#form input:not(.donot)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: `+1` Ha! that is true :-P I did not even think of that.